# Prove that $2AK=BP+PC$ in isosceles triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

> Let $ABC$ is isosceles triangle. $AB=AC$. Point $P$ such that $\angle BPC=2\angle BAC$. $PK$ is bisector of $\angle BPD$ and $AK \perp PK$. Prove that $$2AK=BP+PC$$

**My attempts:**

Let point $A'$ and $B'$ such that $AK=KA'$ and $PB=PB'$. Then need prove that $AA'=B'C$.

This is equivalent to proving that the $ACA'B'$ is an isosceles trapezoid.

I dont know how use that $\angle BPC=2\angle BAC$ and $AB=AC$
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $∠BPC = 2∠BAC$ and $∠DPK = ∠FPK \Rightarrow ∠FDP = ∠DFP$, then $$∠FDP = ∠DFP = \frac{1}{2} ∠BPC = ∠BAC.$$
Therefore,\begin{gather*}
∠ABF = ∠DFP - ∠BAF = ∠BAC - ∠BAF = ∠CAD,\\
∠BAF = ∠BAC - ∠CAD = ∠FDP - ∠CAD = ∠ACD.
\end{gather*}
Since $BA = AC$, then$$
△ABF ≌ △CAD. \quad \text{(ASA)}
$$
Note that $DP = FP$ and $DK = KF$, thus$$
BP + PC = BF + CD = AD + AF = 2AK.
$$